# Quad moves when screen is resized verticly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a quad drawn on the screen, positioned at the top of the screen and centred. As I resize the screen so it is not as high, the quad appears to move in the opposite direction from what it should, IE, up at the same rate it should be going down on my monitor.

It is constantly being set to be at the top of the screen and centred each loop, before rendering.

```
this.location[0] = (Display.getWidth()/2)-(this.size[0]/2);
this.location[1] = 0;
```

Then I render the quad and print out its `Y` location. this consistently returns `0`, no matter what I resize the window to. By printing out the mouse coordinates I can confirm that the top of the screen is `0` when it is resized. Why is it then, that even though I am setting the quad to be at `0`, then rendering it **exactly after**, it still isn't drawn at `0`?

Is there some Opengl or LWJGL concept I don't understand?

Here's the Opengl Setup code.

```
    GL11.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight(),0 ,1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: What are you doing when the window was resized? Usually people set the viewport based on the size retrieved in a resize method.

Comment: @JackWhiteIII nothing. Do I need to move a camera or something?

Comment: i don't know, it's been ages since I used OpenGL. Try calling your OpenGL setup code again if the window was resized.

Comment: @JackWhiteIII Hasn't worked. So I can write better questions in future, why has this gotten voted down?

Comment: Nobody has an answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has answered this, and I have found a solution, inefficient as it may be, here's an answer.

I Changed the line

```
glOrtho(0,Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight(), 0 ,1, -1);
```

to

```
glOrtho(0,Display.getWidth(), 0,Display.getHeight(),1, -1);
```

Which means instead of the top being the top, the top is now the bottom of the screen. I then had to create another variable inside my box class, called `realY` which is the actual y coordinate of the box/quad's left hand corner.

Then with some simple math (`this.realY = (Display.getHeight() - this.location[1])-this.size[1];`) I convert the input Y into the upside down version of itself, so 0 becomes the height of the screen, and vise versa

To me, this seems like a inefficient solution, and more of a workaround. If anyone has a better answer, please post it.